# How to recalculate vertex normals after transforming a mesh in Python

Tags: python, transforms, normals

```py
import bpy
from bpy import data as D
from bpy import context as C
from mathutils import *
from math import *

# work on the default startup scene
me = D.meshes['Cube']
print([v.normal for v in me.vertices])
me.transform(Matrix.Rotation(2, 4, 'X'))
me.calc_normals()
print([v.normal for v in me.vertices])
```

Running the script with `blender -P transform.py` outputs the same values twice. The `calc_normals` call seems to have no effect. How can I properly recalculate the normals instead?

Replacing `calc_normals` with two `flip_normals` calls works, but is kind of an ugly workaround.

Looking in Blender's source code, the `transform` intentionally does not touch the normals, a comment says "don't update normals, caller can do this explicitly". And `calc_normals` first looks if the normals are dirty, which they aren't, and does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug in Blender 3.1 and has since been fixed.